# An error occurred while loading the archive

Tags: 22.04, zip, file-roller

I have a strange issue. I had a folder and compressed it using the default tool in Windows 11. After I put it on OneDrive, I downloaded it on my Linux machine. I waited 1 hour for it to be completed, and after, I tried to open it as I did with many files before. When I try to open it, I receive an error: "An error occurred while loading the archive." I found this error more often than it should be. It might be a corruption in the network, but it is not. The "file-roller" version is '3.42.0'. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I did not added any password to the zip file.

And when I am trying to unzip from the terminal using the 'unzip' command I get this error:

```
"warning [filename]  15657336822 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [filename] :  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
"
```

Do you have any idea what I can do in this situation?

Comment: This issue was covered over on the Unix & Linux board -- see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589925/how-to-fix-onedrive-corrupt-zips-with-a-bash-script/590034#590034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the apt OneDrive application to download the file and 7 zip to unzip the file and now it is working.